# Filter on AWS appflow with or Condition

Tags: filter, aws-cloudformation, amazon-appflow, or-condition

I'm trying to filter only the ownerid with two particular values (a,b)while setup of Appflow through Cloudformation , but the documentation doesn't help . using the console I can impost the filter bu can't set the right configuration using Cloudformation

```
  Tasks: 
    - TaskType: Filter
      SourceFields:
        - OwnerId
      ConnectorOperator:
        Salesforce: EQUAL_TO 
      TaskProperties:
        - Key: DATA_TYPE
          Value: JSONArray
        - Key: VALUES
          Value: "['a','b']"   
    - TaskType: Filter
      ConnectorOperator:
        Salesforce: PROJECTION
      SourceFields: 
        - OwnerId
    - TaskType: Map
      ConnectorOperator:
        Salesforce: NO_OP
      SourceFields:
        - OwnerId
      DestinationField: OwnerId
      TaskProperties:
        - Key: DESTINATION_DATA_TYPE
          Value: text
        - Key: SOURCE_DATA_TYPE
          Value: text
    - TaskType: Map_all
      SourceFields: []
      TaskProperties:
        - Key: EXCLUDE_SOURCE_FIELDS_LIST
          Value: "[]"
      ConnectorOperator:
        Salesforce: NO_OP
```

Comment: Were you able to find out how to use filters in the config?

Comment: Yes , - Key: VALUES
          Value: "a,b" you will need to use the first key value

Comment: Could you post your solution?  I'm struggling with this right now too TT